# Programmatic implementation of iCarousel Swift example

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, icarousel

Here is a Storyboard example of iCarousel implementation in Swift: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/tree/master/Examples/Swift%20Example

Particularly this page:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/blob/master/Examples/Swift%20Example/SwiftExample/ViewController.swift

Can somebody guide me how to implement it programmatically (without Storyboards)?

Answer (score 1):

swift 3

```
private let HEIGHT_CAROUSEL: CGFloat = 100
        private func initiCarousel() {
            let carousel = iCarousel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - HEIGHT_CAROUSEL, width: view.frame.width, height: HEIGHT_CAROUSEL))
            carousel.delegate = self
            carousel.dataSource = self
            view.addSubview(carousel)
        }

    // MARK: - iCarouselDelegate
    extension YourNameViewController: iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate {
        func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
            return arrr.count ?? 0
        }

        func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
            var itemView: UIImageView
            itemView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: HEIGHT_CAROUSEL, height: HEIGHT_CAROUSEL))
            itemView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            if let image = url {
                itemView.setImageWithIndicator(imageUrl: image)
            }

            return itemView
        }

        func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            if (option == .spacing) {
                return value * 1.1
            }
            return value
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to implement iCarousel programmatically using swift:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    carousel = iCarousel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
    carousel.center = view.center
    carousel.dataSource = self
    carousel.delegate = self
}
```